# Can I insert text into the console input buffer?

Tags: c#, input, console

To start off, I don't even know if I used the proper terminology. What I'm talking about is let's say I have a program that displays the value of a string and it also allows me to edit the value. What I want to do is when I begin to edit the value, the original value will be placed in my input so it'll be as if I manually typed in the original value and am able to use backspace and stuff.

It's like I just changed the value to a very long sentence and I realized I misspelled one word so when I edit the value the original pops up so I can use the arrow keys to move to the word and fix it, instead of having to retype the entire sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to use a C# wrapper for the [curses](http://sourceforge.net/projects/curses-sharp/) terminal control library.